# When to use JSONB type for such a column?

Tags: postgresql

I am designing some schema in my Postgres 12. And I have an entity (lets call it "Laptop") with an attribute (lets call it "Properties") like:

```
{ <someKey>: { <someLabel>: <someValue> } }
```

For example, the laptop has these properties:

```
{ "cpu": { "count": 8, "model": "Core i7" },
  "disk": { "size": 123456789, "model": "Samsung", "speed": 7200 },
  ...
}
```

And each laptop has own set of properties...

And now I have to choose how to implement it: as tables or just as a JSON/JSONB column in the table "laptops". What are the criteria / principles when to use JSON/JSONB columns or to design such attributes as tables?

Comment: Will you need to query independent items within the JSON string?  Yes?  Don't use JSON. Do I need the structure clearly defined and no deviation in data elements/types? Yes? Don't use JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb is: if the data are just payload to the database and will never be used in `WHERE` conditions and the like, use `json`. Else, use `jsonb`.